# How to return boolean values for checkbox checked and unchecked in ANGULAR Material 6

Tags: checkbox, angular6, angular-material-6

The concept i would want to get is 
ON selection of a checkbox i want the value to be returned as TRUE 
and 
ON de-selection of the same checkbox i want the value to be returned as False

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" type= checkbox value = "true" formControlName ="rti_cover" [checked] = "true">RTI</mat-checkbox>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" type= checkbox value = "true" formControlName ="nildep_cover" [checked] = "true" >Nil Dep</mat-checkbox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the checkbox by binding to the (change) EventEmitter. You can see this in the documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api

In your component you can create a function that listens for the (change) event, and pass the event from your template.

```
checkboxChanged(event) {
  console.log(event.checked);
}
```

The event contains the property "checked" which is a boolean representing whether the box is checked or not.

In your template you can then bind to the event:

```
<mat-checkbox (change) = "checkboxChanged($event)">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```